# Firestore custom `toObject` deserialization

Tags: android, serialization, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore in an Android project.
I have a `Transaction` model that has a `org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime date` field.

When I'm trying to deserialize a `DocumentReference` into a `Transaction` model by calling `docRef.toObject(Transaction.class`) I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime (found in field 'date')

This is expected as the server returns the date as a string.
Is it possible to use a custom de-serializer?

I know that I can ditch the use of the `toObject` method and write custom code, but it feels wasteful as I only need custom de-serialization for a single field.
The rest of the fields de-serialize properly.

Comment: I believe the compatible type for Date/Time fields is Java.util.Date. Since you're using String (also compatible), maybe use the Getter/Setter methods for the date-related fields of your custom class to convert LocalDateTime to String and vice versa?

Comment: @KaranModi that's what I end up doing, but preferred if I was able to apply transformations to specific field when using the `toObject` method.

Answer (score -1):

Firebase Database and Cloud Firestore cannot serialize arbitrary Java objects to the database. You'll have to write code to pick just the properties that you want to store.

If you're having problems writing this code, show what you've tried and we can have a look.

See (most of these are for the Realtime Database, but the same logic applies to Cloud Firestore):

- [Save object of LocalDate (Java.time) in Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473473/save-object-of-localdate-java-time-in-firebase-database)
- [Inserting Firebase date field on SQLite as String with SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047421/inserting-firebase-date-field-on-sqlite-as-string-with-simpledateformat)
- [Firebase with Realm. De-serializing POJO class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643460/firebase-with-realm-de-serializing-pojo-class)

Comment: Hi, I was actually asking regarding de-serialization, not serialization.
This does work out of the box using the `toObject` method, however I couldn't find a way to provide custom de-serialization logic.